# How to remove the worldmap from nasa worldwind

Tags: swing, worldwind

I am working on a project related with nasa worldwind.

Can anybody explain me that ,hw can I remove the worldmap ,which is

located at the top left of screen.

Comment: Are you talking about the SDK?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a custom layers.xml file you can comment out the following line in order to remove the map:

```
<Layer className="gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.WorldMapLayer"/>
```

If you are using the worldwind.layers.xml that is bundled in the worldwind.jar file you would need to add the following code to remove it

```
Layer worldMapLayer = worldWindowGLCanvas1.getModel().getLayers().getLayerByName("World Map");
worldWindowGLCanvas1.getModel().getLayers().remove(worldMapLayer);
```

You need to insert this code after worldWindGLCanvas is created, but before any LayerPanel (if used) is created.